# Language URI redirect to Subdomain with Htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a easy question for you...
I need redirect a old URL with the possible content in URI, like that:

```
www.mywebsite.com/en
www.mywebsite.com/en/another-page
```

to

```
en.mywebsite.com
en.mywebsite.com/another-page
```

Somebody have a solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as your very first rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?mywebsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^en(?:/(.*))?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for that @anubhava
But, if I need set the site base URL, this way?

`RedirectMatch 301 ^mysite.com/en(?:/(.*))?$    /$1`

Comment: No domain is not matched, only start of URI after domain name.

Comment: Hi again @anubhava

Sorry for that, but I have many domains in the htaccess and i need to specify the domain name.

Comment: Dude, you're amazing, thank so mutch for that!
This works fine!